# Margin is no longer an issue when applying background color to body?

Tags: css

I am working on a video project explaining some CSS concepts. I wanted to show how the body element has a default margin applied.

This definitely used to be an issue in the past where you needed to reset the margin if you intended to uses a background color.

I just tried in every major browser and this behavior is not happening. If I set a background color, even though the body has a margin of 8px be default in chrome, the background color extends to the edges of the screen.

This is even "fixed" in IE for me.

What happened??

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: if html has no background set, then body background is drawn from/within html ... try 2 diffrent bg-colors to body and html  to see that behavior

Answer (score 1):

CSS properties on `<body>` have [special interpretation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds) due to backwards compatibility. It all gets [even weirder in quirks mode](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-body-element-fills-the-html-element-quirk), so make sure your pages always have a valid modern DOCTYPE (e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html>`).

It's part of the spec, and most browsers are spec-compliant these days.

For example, when `background` is set on `<body>`, and there is no background set on the `<html>` element, [it's interpreted as `<html>`'s background instead](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#body-background).

Comment: How long has this been happening? I could have sworn this was an issue for me very recently.

Comment: These quirks are as old as background colors. There have been attempts to remove them, e.g. in XHTML mode. Note that you'll get different behavior when both `html` and `body` have different backgrounds set. There's also an interaction between margins of body and elements *in* the body (margin collapsing) that might sometimes be visible.